# How to actualize JProgressBar in Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, user-interface

In my school project (simple Swing application) I have a class that does some computational stuff (trains neural network) and this computation runs in iterations. I would like to actualize some GUI components (`JProgressBar`) and show to the user what iteration is actually processed (e.g. 100/10000).

I would like to ask how to accomplish it with respect to application design. I don't want to mix computation code with code for refreshing GUI components. Is it a proper situation to use Observer design pattern? If so, I can set my computation class as an observable object and register observer - class that will actualize `JProgressBar`.

Is it ok or is there some better way how to achieve it?

Comment: Having some sort of ComputationObserver sounds like a good way.

Comment: The progress bar needs to be updated manually directly or indirectly so with respect to *"don't want to mix computation code with ... "* you do have to put something in there.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much time your computation takes, you should also consider [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). Also having observer or some kind of handler which will update gui is good idea.

Comment: The computation takes few seconds (5-10).